# Infinite sum evaluation (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho ^k}{k} \cos (k \theta) = - \frac{1}{2} \log(1 -2 \rho \cos(\theta) + \rho ^2)$$ with $\rho < 1$ .

I'm quite sure I can use that expansion $\operatorname{Log}(1-z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}$, but I don't know how to treat the term $\cos(k \theta)$.

Any hint?

Comment: $\cos{k\theta}$ is the real part of $e^{ik\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\log(1-z) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}$ you write 
$$
- \frac{1}{2} \log(1 -2 \rho \cos(\theta) + \rho ^2) \\
= - \frac{1}{2} \log((1 - \rho e^{i \theta})(1 - \rho e^{-i \theta}) \\
= - \frac{1}{2}\log(1 - \rho e^{i \theta}) - \frac{1}{2} \log(1 - \rho e^{-i \theta})) \\
=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho ^k}{k} (e^{i k\theta} + e^{-i k \theta}) \\
=  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho ^k}{k} \cos (k \theta) 
$$